# Link error: lnk1104 cannot open file freeglut.lib

Tags: cmake, freeglut

I'm trying to build and run [InfiniTAM](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evictor/infinitam/) ([Github page](https://github.com/victorprad/InfiniTAM)).

The Github page lists a whole lot of dependencies I already have got most of them, except for freeglut.
So I follow [this tutorial to install freeglut using MinGW64](https://medium.com/@bhargav.chippada/how-to-setup-opengl-on-mingw-w64-in-windows-10-64-bits-b77f350cea7e).

Next I clone the InfiniTAM repo and start up CMake GUI, select the repo folder as source and create a build folder as Target.
Configuring (For Visual Studio 2019, 64bit) results in the following error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:

GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/MyName/source/repos/InfiniTAM/InfiniTAM/Apps/InfiniTAM
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/MyName/source/repos/InfiniTAM/InfiniTAM/InputSource
GLUT_LIBRARY
    linked by target "InfiniTAM" in directory C:/Users/Johannes/source/repos/InfiniTAM/InfiniTAM/Apps/InfiniTAM
```

So here is what I did (and where I suspect my error).

1. Set `GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR` to the 'include' folder within my freeglut directory (which I copied directly to C:\FreeGLUT)
2. In the freeglut folder, there is a lib folder containing two files: `libfreeglut.dll.a` and `libfreeglut_static.a`. I tried to set `GLUT_LIBRARY` to both of them, each resulting the same error in the next step.

Next I press configure again (no without error), generate the project and open it in Visual Studio.
I change output to `Release` and try to build the solution. This always leads to the following error:

> **Link error: lnk1104 cannot open file freeglut.lib**

There are a few posts about these error about, however I'm trying to build a finished (tested) product, so the problem surely isn't within the code, but somewhere in my setup.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 cannot use MinGW libraries. You need either 1. Build the project for MinGW, by choosing appropriate CMake generator. In that case your freeGLUT installation is suitable. 2. Build the project for Visual Studio, and install freeGLUT for Visual Studio.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, OK I'll try to build freeGLUT with VS and report back here if it worked.

Comment: Additional Question: Should one use `freeglut.lib` or `freeglut_static.lib` ?

Comment: This seems like selecting between **shared** and **static** libraries. Generally such choice is up to you. Don't know about freeGLUT specifically.

Comment: I used `freeglut.lib` and it did the trick! If you put your comment into an answer post, I'll mark it. Thanks a bunch!